# Is class casting allowed?

Tags: oop, class, casting, type-conversion

I have 2 public classes; Person and Engineer. Engineer is inherited from Person class.
Now in main() I have a person object say

```
Person abc = new Person();
```

and I am trying to convert "abc" to Engineer i.e.

```
Engineer xyz = (Engineer) abc;
```

***Question:*** Is this legal? My understanding is I cannot do it because "abc" might have different attributes.

***Code:***

```
public class Person { 
      private String firstname; 
      private String lastname; 
      private String gender; 

      public Person(String first, String last, String gen) { 
            firstname = first; 
            lastname = last; 
            gender = gen; 
      } 

      public void setFirstName(String name) { 
            firstname = name; 
      } 

      public void setLastName(String name) { 
            lastname = name; 
      } 

      public void setGender(String gen) { 
            gender = gen; 
      } 

      public String getFirstName() { 
            return firstname; 
      } 

      public String getLastName() { 
            return lastname; 
      } 

      public String getGender() { 
            return gender; 
      } 

     public toString() { 
            return "firstname=" + firstname + "lastname=" + lastname + "gender=" + gender; 
} 

public class SoftwareEngineer extends Person { 
      public String teamname; 
      public String bestlanguage; 

      public SoftwareEngineer(String first, String last, String gen, String team, String lang) { 
            firstname = first; 
            lastname = last; 
            gender = gen; 
            teamname = team; 
            bestlanguage = lang; 
      } 

     public toString() { 
            return "firstname=" + firstname + "lastname=" + lastname + "gender=" + gender + "teamname=" + teamname + "bestlanguage=" + bestlanguage; 


} 

public void main() { 
SoftwareEngineer aaron = new SoftwareEngineer('Aaron','Gottlieb','M','IPSupport','SQL'); 
Person andy = new SoftwareEngineer('Andy','Gardner','M','IP','Java'); 
Person pete = new Person("Pete", "G", "M"); 


Person personAaron = aaron; 
SoftwareEngineer sePete = (SoftwareEngineer) pete; 
SoftwareEngineer seAndy = (SoftwareEngineer) andy; 
pete.teamname = "FooBar"; 
aaron.setLastName("Brian"); 

}
```

Comment: What language are you talking about?

Comment: Depends entirely on the language and the relationship of person to engineer.

Comment: Wait I will post the code I am trying to understand

Answer (score 0):

Every *engineer* is a *person*, but not every *person* is an *engineer*. Now translate it to your OO domain. Do you think you can always cast `Person` to `Engineer`? I.e. assume that every *person* is an *engineer*?

No, but you can ask *person*: *are you an engineer?*:

```
if(abc instanceof Engineer) {
  Engineer xyz = (Engineer) abc;
}
```

But you don't always have to know that. You can ask *every* person about name, it doesn't matter whether that person is an engineer or not:

```
Person p = new Engineer();
p.getFirstName();
```

Comment: Okay I understood the concept you just explained to me... Now what I have in the above code is: Person andy = new SoftwareEngineer('Andy','Gardner','M','IP','Java'); and I an trying to convert "SoftwareEngineer seAndy = (SoftwareEngineer) andy;" which I guess should be valid now

Comment: @tech_learning: it is valid in this particular situation, but not always, e.g. when there is `SoftwareEngineer` and `MechanicalEngineer` - you have no guarantee what kind of engineer hides behind a person. Attributes have nothing to do here, it's about types.